# boolean values, run time error if not 0 or 1

Tags: c, boolean, logic

> boolean values, run time error if not 0 or 1

I wanted to hear how you understand this question. Would I be - if using this C variant - allowed to write a codeblock like this:

```
int b = 2;
if (b == 2) { 
    return 3;
}
```

Is it the return value that cannot be 3? I don't understand the sentence correctly I believe. Could someone give me an example of how an invalid conditional statement would look like in this C variant? Learning about Boolean values.

Comment: `if (2)` for example, since integer could be used as a conditional and currently anything which is not 0 considered true and 0 is false.

Comment: *"Would I be - if using this C variant - allowed to write a codeblock like this:"* `b` is uninitialized so this is undefined behavior even in "normal" C.

Comment: Sorry Blaze, assume it's initialized to 2 (edited).

Comment: A typical example would be `if (strcmp(a, b))` where `strcmp` may return any* non-zero `int` when the strings are not equal. Of course that can be circumvented simply with `if (strcmp(a, b) != 0)` (which I would consider better style anyway). * theoretically

Comment: so you would not be able to create a function and use it in an if-statement if it returned something else than 0 or 1?

Comment: `#define if(x) if(!!(x))` ... `if (foo - 42)` ==> `if (!!(foo - 42))` == `if (foo != 42)`, see https://ideone.com/bTUVhR

Comment: @Lubbi You can map any return value to 0 or 1, e.g., `!!my_function()` or `my_function() ? 1 : 0` or `my_function() != 0`.

Comment: @Lubbi You could. But instead of writing `if(func())` you would have to write `if(func() != 0)` – or if it returns a pointer perhaps better `if(func() != NULL)`...

Comment: @pmg You just proved that the preprocessor would allow to circumvent that limitation...

Comment: Also note that there are already other programming languages that have this property, i.e., the `if` condition has to have a boolean type. In practice it doesn't lead to any particular inconvenience, you simply compare the value with `==` or `!=` to get a boolean. In fact I would say that C's behaviour is more unusual/surprising than this variant would be, except that C has been around for so long that we are accustomed to its quirks. (And back in the the day they probably seemed very reasonable when coming from assembly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` always evaluates to `0` or `1` so it can never cause a runtime error in your hypothetical scenario.

`if(2)` or `if(3)` would be a runtime error in your hypothetical, in "normal" C these expressions evaluate to `true`, so the cycle will be executed, in fact any value that is not `0`, either `positive` or `negative`, evaluates to `true`.

**An example of the advantages of evaluating values other than `0` or `1` would be the [`strcmp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function:**

> It will return `0` if the parameter `strings` (`char` arrays to be more 
>   precise) are equal, a `negative` value if the first parameter appears before the second parameter in lexicographical order, or a `positive` value if it is  the other way around.
>
> In this case you will want to know if the strings are equal or not, so
>   in `if(strcmp(a, b))` (being `a` and `b`, strings), if `strcmp()`returns `30` or `-2`, your expression is still good in "normal" C. The expression will evaluate to `true` and you  will know the strings are different.

**A sample advantage of having errors if the expression evaluates to values other than `0` or `1` would be this case:**

> If you mistakenly write `if(a = 2)` when trying to write `if(a == 2)`.
>   The mistaken expression will evaluate to `2`, `a` will be assigned the value of `2`, and this will evaluate to `true` regardless of the previous value of `a`, the mistake will be hard to detect since the code compiles fine. A runtime error would help detect the mistake.`*`.

`*` Note that there is a safeguard for these errors if you turn on your compiler warnings, but this would be a direct way, there are languages that do not allow you to evaluate conditional expressions with values other than `1 (true)` or `0 (false)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Makes better sense now. But when would someone ever use an if statement like that? "if (2)" or "if (3)"?. Wow thank you. I misunderstood that question entirely

Comment: The example in the comment section, [`strcmp(a, b)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) will return a value of 0 if the strings are equal, a negative value if first parameter string appears before the second parameter string in lexicographical order and a positive value if it is the other way arround. In this case you will want to know if the strings are equal or not, so if strcmp returns 300, your expression is still good in "normal" C.

Answer (score 1):

`if(condition) { a(); } else { b(); }` executes `a();` if `condition` is non-zero and `b();` if `condition` is zero.

That means that setting `condition` to other values like `2` or `3` would have the same effect as setting it to `1`. The way I understand your idea, these other values would now lead to runtime errors.

That would be irrelevant for operators like `==` or `!=` because they only ever evaluate to `0` or `1` anyway, but it would make a difference for something like `char* pointer = malloc(10); if(pointer)` or `if(strcmp(a, b))` (because the latter could also evaluate to `-1`).

Answer (score 0):

Standard C allows any scalar expression (any arithmetic or pointer expression) for the controlling expression of `if` and `while` statements, and the expression is taken as “true” if it is not zero (or, for a pointer, null). This means we can write statements such as `if (p) { … }`, where `p` is a pointer, and it will execute the `{ … }` if and only if `p` is not a null pointer. That is convenient in various ways.

However, it also means errors can occur. A programmer might accidentally write `x & 3 | y` where they intend `x & 3 || y`. The latter always has a value of 0 or 1, because the `||` operator returns 1 if either operand is not zero and 0 if both are zero. But `x & 3 | y` may have a value other than 0 or 1. So a variant of C which gave a run-time error for this could help catch this error during testing.

Effectively, the proposed change requires controlling expressions to evaluate to only the Boolean values 0 or 1, thus inducing programmers to write more strictly Boolean expressions rather than the free-form expressions standard C allows. It is not a perfect change, as some arithmetic expressions may evaluate only to 0 or 1 even though they are not proper Boolean expressions (for example, we generally consider `x & 1` to be doing some bit manipulation rather than being a Boolean test like `x == 13`, but it evaluates to only 0 or 1), so the change will not completely restrict controlling expressions to being Boolean expressions. A better change to accomplish this goal would further modify the grammar or constraints so that controlling expressions had to be Boolean expressions.

Comment: It would also need to forbid the assignment from an integer. So the only valid values for assignment to a boolean would be the literals `true` and ``false` and any comparison expression. Or another boolean or function returning boolean. It could be enforced at compile time. [it would even be worse than Java ...]